# Remove Element From Array by String (text) instead of Index

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to remove the element form the array. Actually I don't know the the index of the element and want to remove through it's value. I have tried a lot but fail. This is the function which i used to add element in the Array

```
    string [] Arr;
    int i = 0;
    public void AddTOList(string ItemName)
    {
        Arr[i] = ItemName;
        i++;
    }
```

And I want to remove the element by the value. I know the below function is wrong but I want to explain what I want:

```
    public void RemoveFromList(string ItemName)
    {
        A["Some_String"] = null;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm failing to understand how you would add items to an array with the example you have.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to remove items by a string key then use a `Dictionary`

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, int>();

d.Add("Key1", 3);

int t = d["Key1"];
```

Or something like that.

Comment: perhaps `HashSet` if the indexed value is not important.

Answer (score 2):

`Array` has a fixed size, which is not suitable for your requirement. Instead you can use `List<string>`.

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
//add an item
myList.Add("hi");
//remove an item by its value
myList.Remove("hi");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(A);
list.Remove(ItemName);
A = list.ToArray();
```

and @see Array.Resize
and @see Array.IndexOf

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through every value in array and if found then remove it. Something like this

```
        string[] arr = new string[] { "apple", "ball", "cat", "dog", "elephant", "fan", "goat", "hat" };
        string itemToRemove = "fan";
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] == itemToRemove)
            {
                arr[i]=null;
                break;
            }
        }
```